# Is It possible to reduce the resolution of a video in android using intent?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the below to reduce the video resolution.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

i did some research and found that this is not working for Samsung devices. so is there another way to use the native camera. i know i can use Media Recorder and choose the desired the default resolution, but then i wont have other camera functionality like zooming for example.

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you want to break in the settings of every camera app that's on the market right now to edit the setting. That comes with another problem, the user didn't chose the video quality for no reason, so you must change it back to it's original value, or this is a no-go and you need to develop you're own recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so is there another way to use the native camera

You are not using "the native camera". You are using whatever camera application the user elects to have handle your request. There is no requirement that any such camera application honor `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` or honor it in the same way.